# Why is my C++ code outputting NSString literals rather than plaintext?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I know this question seems odd, as NSString doesn't exist in C++. Yet, for some reason, when I run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I see the following output:

```objectivec
@"Hello, World!\r\n"
```

The C functions `printf` and `puts` show similar behavior. I also see the same output if I store the text as a `std::string` and then display that.

I have no idea how to even start troubleshooting this. What is going on?

Comment: Where do you see this output? Describe the steps you are taking.

Comment: What does `NSString` have to do with this code? Have you tried stepping through this code with a debugger to see what it is really doing?

Comment: Are you using MacOS and Visual Studio Code ? If yes try to set "externalConsole" in launch.json to true  ... something like this "externalConsole" : true

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's the syntax for an NSString literal in Objective-C.

Comment: @SamuelB. Yes I am, but changing that to `true` causes a linker error.

Comment: @Bbrk24 I think you are confusing things. Your **code** is not using an NSString literal, otherwise it would be using `cout << @"Hello, World!" << endl`.  The fact that your **console** is displaying your C string in NSString format would be an implementation detail of the console itself, or maybe of the `std::streambuf` object that your compiler's standard library is attached to `std::cout` by default. But the fact that `printf()` and `puts()` are also affected makes me thing the issue is in the console. But the library implementation is not out of the realm of possibility, either.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that's what I'm really asking about. Why is it displaying like that and how can I change it?

Comment: @Bbrk24 Can you provide a screenshot of what you are seeing? But why do you want to change it? Clearly your **environment** is setup to display strings that way.  Your **code** shouldn't care, it simply told `cout` to display a string, and it did its job. The rest is handled outside of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a while ago but I forgot about my own question.

In the debug window, it just displays output like that. It only gets formatted like that in debug mode; if I compile it and run the executable from the command line, then it works as expected.